# Cartthrob: Controlling tax on products using multi_add_to_cart_form

Tags: cartthrob

Hoping someone can help me with this...

We are using the **multi_add_to_cart_form** to create custom product packages. The site sells classes and the client is offering a class add-on that can be added to the cart when the class is added to the cart. Classes are in one channel, add-ons are in another channel. The add-ons are added to classes via Playa. This works great to create a nice class page with selectable add-ons.

Here's my dilemma - **classes are not taxable. The add-on products are.** How can I allow tax to be applied to the products, but not the classes when they are added to the cart??

If I use:

```
{exp:cartthrob:multi_add_to_cart_form 
    tax_exempt="yes"
    shipping_exempt="yes"
    return="store/cart"
}
```

Nothing is taxed. And if I remove the tax_exempt="yes", everything is taxed. Any way to work around this? Maybe a way to pass a tax variable via hidden field?

Looking forward to any suggestions! And I will buy you many beers! :-)

Thanks,
Danielle

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried the hidden input method?

[ input type="hidden" name="tax_exempt[#]" value="yes" ]

Would be interested to know if this works too.

Comment: We tried that, but it did not work.